# Numpy check datatype each its value and return boolean

Tags: python, numpy

I do

```
np.array([1,2])==int
```

but it gives

```
array([False, False])
```

while I expect it to be

```
array([True, True])
```

what should I do to return what I expect?

Comment: Your expression is testing the value of each element.  It is not checking "datatype".  I'd suggest doing some more reading of the numpy into.  Each array has a `dtype` property.  That's all you need to check.  That test also does not apply to basic Python objects like lists and numbers.

Comment: Note that one of the points of a NumPy array is that all elements have the same data type. That's why, as hpaulj says, the `dtype` is a property of the whole array, and you would need to check it only once per array, not for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you test the type of elements of a list:

```
In [94]: alist = [1, 2.3, [1,2,3],'a']
In [95]: [isinstance(i, int) for i in alist]
Out[95]: [True, False, False, False]
In [96]: [isinstance(i, str) for i in alist]
Out[96]: [False, False, False, True]
```

For an array:

```
Out[98]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [99]: arr.dtype
Out[99]: dtype('int64')
In [100]: arr = np.array([1,2,3.0])
In [101]: arr
Out[101]: array([1., 2., 3.])
In [102]: arr.dtype
Out[102]: dtype('float64')
```

Note that in [101] all values display as float, even though in the source, [100] only one was a float.  A list contains elements by reference; in arrays its by value (except for a list like object dtype).